# How to transfer data between two fragment with RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, data-transfer

I tried to transfer data from **View Fragment** which contains RecycleView to **Display Fragment**... but I'm getting null Exception Error every time while using bundle

Here is my code.

**Inside Adapter**

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        StringIntString ping=arrayList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(ping.getmString());
        holder.desc.setText(ping.getnString());
        holder.num.setText(Integer.toString(ping.getmInt()));
        holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("name", ping.getmString());
                bundle.putString("desc", ping.getnString());
                bundle.putString("num",Integer.toString(ping.getmInt()));
                DisplayFrag frag=new DisplayFrag();
                frag.setArguments(bundle);

                
                ((FragmentActivity)view.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.slide_out).replace(R.id.fragview,DisplayFrag.class,null).commit();
            }
        });

    }
```

**Inside Display view**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewfrag2, container, false);
        name=v.findViewById(R.id.box1);
        desc=v.findViewById(R.id.box2);
        num=v.findViewById(R.id.box3);
        Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();
      // if(bundle != null) {
           name.setText(bundle.getString("name"));
           desc.setText(bundle.getString("desc"));
           num.setText(bundle.getInt("num"));
      // }
        return v;
    }
```

*Log Message*

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 31856
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
> at com.example.myapplication.DisplayFrag.onCreateView(DisplayFrag.java:31)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1899)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1817)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1760)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:547)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

I'm expecting to transfer data **from View fragment to Display fragmnet**

Comment: Check in your logcat for your data before send them to you bundle, it might be null.

Comment: you can also try this using LiveData

Comment: @MokhtarAbdelhalim yes it is null...

Comment: @Nilabja can you present code for LiveData? I'm kinda new to android...

Comment: There are endless questions on SO about "how to I pass data between fragments" on Android. Please search for one, since it's tiring to reply *every single time* with the same links to the Jetpack documentation, the ViewModel, the FLow/LiveData, etc. Start reading about [app architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture) please. You're going to want to use a [viewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I did learn about app architecture... and i tried to use viewModel... unfortunately it transfers default values such as **null** for string and **0** for Integer. Can you attach any one proper answer's link?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your constants class define new (you can make it Static) variables like below

```
public class MyUtils
{
    public static MutableLiveData<String> nameMutableLiveDataString = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public static MutableLiveData<String> descMutableLiveDataString = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public static MutableLiveData<Integer> numMutableLiveDataString = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

and your `onBindViewHolder` will look something like this

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                StringIntString ping=arrayList.get(position);
                holder.name.setText(ping.getmString());
                holder.desc.setText(ping.getnString());
                holder.num.setText(Integer.toString(ping.getmInt()));
                holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
        
                        MyUtils.nameMutableLiveDataString.postValue(ping.getmString());
                        MyUtils.descMutableLiveDataString.postValue(ping.getnString());
MyUtils.numMutableLiveDataString.postValue(ping.getmInt());
                        // Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                        // bundle.putString("name", ping.getmString());
                        // bundle.putString("desc", ping.getnString());
                        // bundle.putString("num",Integer.toString(ping.getmInt()));
                        DisplayFrag frag=new DisplayFrag();
                        // frag.setArguments(bundle);
        
        
                        ((FragmentActivity)view.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.slide_out).replace(R.id.fragview,DisplayFrag.class,null).commit();
                    }
                });
        
            }
```

and your view class something like this

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewfrag2, container, false);
        name=v.findViewById(R.id.box1);
        desc=v.findViewById(R.id.box2);
        num=v.findViewById(R.id.box3);
        Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();
        // if(bundle != null) {

        MyUtils.nameMutableLiveDataString.observe((LifecycleOwner) this, new Observer<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String s)
            {
                name.setText(s);
            }
        });

        MyUtils.descMutableLiveDataString.observe((LifecycleOwner) this, new Observer<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String s)
            {
                desc.setText(s);
            }
        });

        MyUtils.numMutableLiveDataString.observe((LifecycleOwner) this, new Observer<Integer>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer s)
            {
                num.setText(s.toString());
            }
        });


        // }
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: This code actually Duplicated the number of items in the recyclerview and shows 0 in my display fragment. Am i getting something wrong? i actually copied you're code and corrected with adapter name.

Comment: sorry, my mistake,you need to define MutableLiveData in a global class

Comment: Can you explain me with a code? I'm kinda lost.

Comment: The code work! thank you for sharing the code